# Is it possible to scanf multiple times without a newline in output?

Tags: c, scanf

Im a beginner to c and want to make my code to ask for a command and if 's' is entered it then receives a second number:

```
void get_command(char *command) {
    struct pizzeria *the_pizzeria;
    printf("n - new order, s# - select order #, x - exit\n");
    get_char_input(command, "Command: ", MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH);

}

//....

void process_command(struct pizzeria *the_pizzeria, char *command) {
    if (command[0] == 'n') {
        struct order **last_next_order_field = get_last_next_order_field(the_pizzeria);
        *last_next_order_field = create_order();
    }

    if (command[0] == 's') {
        get_integer_input(&the_pizzeria->selected_order, "");
        printf("\n \n");
    }

}

//....

void get_integer_input(int *variable, char *prompt) {
    
    printf(prompt);
    scanf("%d", variable);

    getchar();

}
```

I want to get a result of: `Command: s2`

However I get receive:

```
Command: s 
2
```

I tried using `getchar()` and `fflush(stdnin)` but it didn't work. I have also attempted `fgets()` and didn't make any progress.

Edit:

Function `get_char_input()`

```
void get_char_input(char *variable, char *prompt, int length) {

    printf(prompt);
    fgets(variable, length, stdin);

    variable[strcspn(variable, "\r\n")] = 0;

}
```

Note: `command` is a `char` variable with the max length of 16.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is only working on some platforms (Windows). Everywhere else that I know, that causees your program to have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the following:

```
printf("n - new order, s# - select order #, x - exit\n");
get_char_input(command, "Command: ", MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH);
```

one 'presumes' that `command` is a multi-character buffer, and you prompt "s#" for entry of "s207" (for example).

This would do what you seem to want:

```
if (command[0] == 's') {
    the_pizzeria->selected_order = atoi( command + 1 );
```

You may want to add validation that the number returned is sensible. It may often be 0.